# Pipeline that Demuxing HLS streams and muxing again

Tags: audio, video, gstreamer, http-live-streaming, gstreamer-1.0

I am trying to generate an MP4 from a HLS stream that contains DISCONTINUITY tags. I am trying to demux and remux the audio and video streams again so that they align.
I tried generating the following pipeline but it doesnt seem to work.

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v souphttpsrc location=<HLSURL> ! hlsdemux ! decodebin name=decoder \
 decoder. ! queue ! x264enc ! mp4mux name=mux ! filesink location=muruga.mp4 \
 decoder. ! queue ! mux.
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: disconti nuity tags , could allow successive segments or blocks of varying dims < W x H >.  difficult to mux to mp4 when dims are not constant

Comment: @RobertRowntree. Thanks for your response. They are from the same source but just that they have been split to show only goals in a match. I tried to only remux the video but that seems to have an issue as well.  `gst-launch-1.0 -v souphttpsrc location=<HLSURL> ! hlsdemux ! decodebin name=decoder ! queue ! x264enc ! mp4mux presentation-time=true ! filesink location=only_video.mp4`